# SpringBoot required a bean of type 'boolean' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring-boot

I search stackoverflow quite a bit, but didn't find a solution for my Problem.
I gte the following error when deploying a SpringBoot app as a WAR file to Tomcat 8, localy it does work fine

```
***************************|
APPLICATION FAILED TO START|
***************************|
Description:
Parameter 0 of method getJobapplicationDTO in 
com.tts.scp.converter.config.ScpDestinationConfig required a bean of 
type 'boolean' that could not be found.
Action:
Consider defining a bean of type 'boolean' in your configuration.
```

There is an Interface

```
public interface HttpProviderConfig {
  JobApplicationDTO getJobapplicationDTO(boolean printResume, boolean 
  printCoverletter, boolean printAttachments, String jobApplicationId);
}
```

and two implementing classes

```
@Configuration
@Profile("production")
public class ScpDestinationConfig implements HttpProviderConfig{

private static final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScpDestinationConfig.class);

@Override
@Bean
public JobApplicationDTO getJobapplicationDTO (boolean resume, boolean coverletter ...
```

and second class

```
@Configuration
@Profile("dev")
public class LocalDestinationConfig implements HttpProviderConfig{

private static final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(LocalDestinationConfig.class);

@Override
@Bean
public JobApplicationDTO getJobapplicationDTO (boolean resume, boolean coverletter ...
```

And a rest service

```
@RestController
public class ConverterController {

private static final Logger logger = 
LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConverterController.class);

@Autowired
@Lazy
private HttpProviderConfig client;

@GetMapping(path = "/convertDocuments", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public void convertedDocument(@RequestParam(defaultValue = "true") String printResume,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "true") String printCoverLetter,
        @RequestParam(defaultValue = "true") String printAttachments, @RequestParam String jobApplicationId,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    JobApplicationDTO jobApplicationDTO = client.getJobapplicationDTO(
```

So waht I don't understand how Tomcat can't find primitive datatypes like boolean and why it does work when i run it locally.

any help would be appreciated

Regards
Mathias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So waht I don't understand how Tomcat can't find primitive datatypes like boolean and why it does work when i run it locally.

This has nothing to do with it.

In your configuration you have a @Bean declaration like:

```
@Bean
public JobApplicationDTO getJobapplicationDTO (boolean resume, ...)
```

So basically you ask Spring to manage the `JobApplicationDTO` for you. Spring then needs `resume` and othe parameters to construct `JobApplicationDTO` for you and it can't find them so you get the error you get.

I think you should not be annotating your `get...DTO` methods with `@Bean` in the first place. And your `...Config` classes actually don't look like a `@Configuration` for me, rather like a `@Service` or `@Component`.

Comment: This is correct. Beans in his case should look like `@Bean HttpProviderConfig httpProviderConfig() {return new ScpDestinationConfig}.`  I don't think @Mathias Maerker fully understands how beans and Configuration works. Some reference: https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html

Comment: Yes your right I don't fully understand what I am doing here ;) but thanks to both of you for your help!